# can any body figure this error?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

In case data is not there it has to empty CEO .in case the data is there it has to show that data

Controller:

```
public with sharing class silogletter {
   public Contact contact {get;set;}
 public silogletter(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
contact = [select Name, MobilePhone, Title,email
         from Contact where AccountId = :controller.getId() and title='CEO'limit 1];
}}
```

vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="silogletter" standardStylesheets="false" contentType="application/msword" >
 <table  border="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding-left:45px;">
        <tr>
       <apex:panelGroup rendered="{!contact.title!='CEO' }">
       <td style="font-size:13px;padding-left:75px;">
            <b>- CEO: </b> <br/>                                              
             <b> Mr/Mrs/Ms.</b><br/>                                                                                           
             <b> tel.:</b>       
        </td>
        <td>
        <b> Email :</b>
        </td>
        </apex:panelgroup>
        <apex:panelGroup rendered="{!contact.title=='CEO'}">
        <td style="font-size:13px;padding-left:75px;">
             <b>- CEO:CEO </b> <br/>                                              
             <b> Mr/Mrs/Ms.</b><apex:outputText value="{!contact.name}"/><br/>                                                                                           
             <b> tel.:</b><apex:outputText value="{!contact.MobilePhone}"/>       
        </td>
        <td>
        <b> Email :</b><apex:outputText value="{!contact.email}" styleClass="none" style="none"  />        
        </td>
        </apex:panelGroup>
       </tr>
       <tr >
```

i am getting this error how can i solve it

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>
> Class.silogletter.: line 8, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no matching contact, you'll get the error, because the variable contact requires exactly one row to be returned from the query when using the inline query syntax.

Use this:

```
public with sharing class silogletter {
   public Contact contact {get;set;}
 public silogletter(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
    for(contact record:[select Name, MobilePhone, Title,email
         from Contact where AccountId = :controller.getId() and title='CEO'limit 1])
        contact = record;
    }
}}
```

If there are no matching contacts, you'll get no results back, and contact will be null.

Comment: in case i have two CEO contact in my account i has to remain null

Comment: If there are two, and you want to have contact be null when this is so, you'll need to query for at least two, then reset to null if you get there. Change `limit 1` to `limit 2`, and change `contact = record;` to `if(contact==null) contact = record; else contact = null;`